# Set a specific status update for users to post to Facebook

Tags: facebook, status

I want to set up a button on my website where I can define a status update for the user who clicks the button?

e.g.: The user clicks the button/link and a popup shows up with my suggested status update. The user just has to agree to post the update, but can also change or edit the text presented to them.

I've seen this for Twitter posts and I'm guessing this is possible for Facebook too.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are referring to [Twitter buttons](https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons).

Previously you were able to accomplish this using the [Facebook Share button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/) but this is deprecated.

Facebook now favors the Like button for a better click rate.

[image: I have already liked the item]

As you can see in the image I have already liked the item, Facebook now gives the option to the user to add a comment.

You may have to get dirty with the Facebook graph and use [FB.ui](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/) instead.

Comment: This is almost what I am looking for... The difference is that I want to define a text. Instead of "Add a comment" I want to have a text. The user can still change it but can also just post it... Is this possible?

Comment: @DanielSchenker Automatically via a plugin? No, not anymore, you are going to have to roll it into an application using the FB.ui. You could try using the old Share button but you will get into problems later on when Facebook drops support for it.